# XMLWriter and php

Tags: php, xml, post

I use [this `XMLWriter`](http://flesler.blogspot.gr/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html) to create an XML file in a javascript function. When I `$_POST` this variable to another php form the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

gets lost. 
Here is how I take and echo the variable

```
$string  = $_POST['mystring'];
echo htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);
```

When I download the file from the page in which is created the xml tag exists. But when I download it from another php page is missing.

Comment: Do you have the XML declaration unescaped in the php file? You should echo it, otherwise it gets intercepted by the php interpreter.

Comment: I thought I did this when I used the htmlspecialchars. Is there anything specific for what you are telling me?

Comment: Well, you were talking about "another php file". Does it go the same there?

Comment: I think there lies the problem. In page1.php I create the xml and I store it in a variable called mystr and I give it as value to an input. In page2.php I use  $_POST['mystring']; where mystring is the name of the input where mystr is stored in page1.php. The echo just give me the rest xml except the first row

Comment: Ok I found the problem and I sovled it, thanks a lot for your time.